# Define what `this` is in a function that is to be called

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this object:

```
var someObject = {
    "collection" : ["aa", "bb", "cc"],
    "each" : function(func){
        for(var i = 0; i < this.collection.length; i++){
            func();
        }
    }
};
```

Now when I run `each` function with this code:

```
someObject.each(function() { console.log(this); });
```

I want it to print the values from `collection` (obviously this is just the description of what the example is supposed to do; I want to do much more complicated things with this). But how do I go about doing that? How do I define what `this` is within a scope of a function that I'm calling?

Yes I'm trying to mimc the behavior of jquery `each` method in my own object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (or [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)) function on `func` to be able to define the `this` within the execution.

```
var someObject = {
    "collection" : ["aa", "bb", "cc"],
    "each" : function(func){
        for(var i = 0; i < this.collection.length; i++){
            func.apply(this.collection[i], [this.collection[i], i]);
        }
    }
};
```

Additionally to defining `this`, I added the element and its index as arguments of the `func` function as an example of passing arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You would write `func.call`. The `call` (or `apply`) methods specify what the value of `this` should be.

Example:

```
var someObject = {
    "collection" : ["aa", "bb", "cc"],
    "each" : function(func){
        for(var i = 0; i < this.collection.length; i++){
            func.call(this.collection[i], /* Arguments */ i); // Pass in the index
        }
    }
};
```

P.S. You could use the native `forEach` method, which automatically comes with each array:

```
someObject.collection.forEach(function(item, index) {
  console.log(item, index);
});
```